# Looping Through ASP.NET Model Data When Using Google Charts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, google-visualization

I have two arrays of data (`DomainName[]` and `DomainCount[]`) that are dynamically set. I would like to use these in an ASP.NET Core application that utilizes the Google Charts API. If the length of the arrays were static, I could program them similar to the API instructions at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

```
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);
```

However, my arrays are not static in length. Is it possible to loop through the array to add to the Google charts data table?

I've tried

```
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            [@Model.DomainName, @Model.DomainCount]
        ]);
```

and

```
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        for (var i = 0; i < @Model.DomainName.Length; i++) {
            //indexer 'i' is not recognized
            data.addRows([@Model.DomainName[i], @Model.DomainCount[i]]);
        }
```

and

```
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        for (var i = 0; i < @Model.DomainName.Length; i++) {
            //this causes a syntax error
            data.addRows([@Model.DomainName+'[' + i + ']', @Model.DomainCount+'[' + i + ']']);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to dynamically assign values to a Google chart. It's not the most elegant solution, so if someone has a better way please share.

```
        //serialize the ASP.NET model data to a JSON object
        var domainName = @Json.Serialize(Model.DomainName);
        var domainCount = @Json.Serialize(Model.DomainCount);
        //the JSON object needs to be cast as a number for the chart
        for (var i = 0; i < domainCount.length; i++) {
            domainCount[i] = parseInt(domainCount[i]);
        }
        //Use 'DataTable' rather than arrayToDataTable in order to use
        // the 'addRows' function
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Number');
        //loop through the serialized array rather than the model data
        // using 'addRows'
        for (i = 0; i < domainCount.length; i++) {
            data.addRows([
                [domainName[i], domainCount[i]]
            ]);
        }

        var options = {
            'title': 'Chart Title',
        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart((document.getElementById('MyChart')));
        chart.draw(data, options);
```